# how do I install Bitcoin Private electrum wallet on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and Im having troubles installing bitcoin private electrum. (NOT the standard electrum wallet)

Here is some info about BTCP - https://btcprivate.org/

Here is the download page: https://github.com/BTCPrivate/electrum-btcp/releases/

Is there a easy way to install this wallet in the terminal?

### I have tried download the 7zip file, extracted it with 7z but then I got stuck. Is it possible to install it with some commands in the terminal I would really appriciate it.

"Download Current Release: https://github.com/BTCPrivate/electrum-btcp/releases/ In case linux you need download source code Source code (zip). Unpack it. Change the directory to the one that was in the archive. Then use instruction below."

Sorry for beeing retarded but Im getting stuck here, I should download the dmg file and the sorce zip file, right?

I did that and extracted the dmg file and got a folder with 4 different folders and text file that says "to install, copy it into applications". 
I tried to do that but failed to do so. Can u please explain very detailed how to do this?

AND, I also dont know what this means or how to do it. "In case linux you need download source code Source code (zip). Unpack it. Change the directory to the one that was in the archive"

Am I suppost do unpack it and put it in the private directory data folder in the electrumBTCPinstaller folder?

---

[image]

Image showing directory for Bitcoin Private Electrum wallet

---

This commands doesnt work:

```
sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" packages.txt  | tr "\n" " ")
pip install -r requirements.txt
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
```

So whats the next step after downloading and unpacking it?

> "In case linux you need download source code Source code (zip). Unpack it. **Change the directory to the one that was in the archive**.

How do I change directory? I don't understand what to do. Can someone explain?

Comment: 7zip file looks for win only (...-**win**.7z)

Comment: The DMG file is for MacOS, you can't use that for anything on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Full installation instruction for linux here: https://github.com/BTCPrivate/electrum-btcp#for-linux

**Download Current Release:** https://github.com/BTCPrivate/electrum-btcp/releases/
In case linux you need download source code **Source code (zip)**.
Unpack it. Change the directory to the one that was in the archive. Then use instruction below.

**Install Dependencies:**

```
sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" packages.txt  | tr "\n" " ")
pip install -r requirements.txt
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
```

**Compile the icons file for Qt:**

```
pyrcc5 icons.qrc -o gui/qt/icons_rc.py
```

**For the Linux app launcher (start menu) icon:**

```
sudo desktop-file-install electrum.desktop
```

**Compile the protobuf description file:**

```
protoc --proto_path=lib/ --python_out=lib/ lib/paymentrequest.proto
```

**Create translations (optional):**

```
./contrib/make_locale
```

**Run:**

```
./electrum-btcp
```

Comment: Thank you @S_flash for your answer. But I still doesnt manage to do the install.

Comment: I have download the Electrum_BTCP-P_1.0.0-py3.6.egg file and the Source code
(tar.gz) file. 
Have unpacked them but there isnt any way to install it? 

https://github.com/BTCPrivate/electrum-btcp/releases/tag/P!1.0.0

When I run this commando it says the file doesnt exist: sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" packages.txt  | tr "\n" " ")

when I run this pip install -r requirements.txt
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] file doesnt exist

So it seems I am missing something, please help me solve this.. been trying to do this install for 3 days now.